# nested use of listing options

Tags: listings

The following code which is built by the `lstlisting` environment from the package `listings`, in my view, should typeset the text "aaa" **with color red**, but the real typeset remains black. I think this is because of nested use of the options `escape` and `leterate`.

So, how to improve my code to get the colored typeset?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper，42pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\aaa{aaa}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,escapeinside='',literate={@}{{\color{red}}}0{|}{{\normalcolor}}0]
@'\aaa'|
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the whole sequence that you want to color is escaped then it may be easy to do the coloring inside of the escape, like `\def\cred{\color{red}}\def\cnorm{\normalcolor}` and then `'\cred\aaa\cnorm'`. But if you go in and out of the escape like `normal code '\aaa' other code '\bbb' more code` and you want to color everything then this becomes tedious with coloring every element individually either with `literate` or inside the escape.

Comment: Thank you @Marijn for your ideal to deal with the problem out of `lstlisting`. I wonder if there is a better way to do it within the scope of `listings`.

Comment: IIRC, the `literate` are executed in their own group scope, so your `\color` approach can't work like this.

Comment: So, does that mean options of `listings` can not be nested used? Nothing can do with it?